# While recording the script, scripts records the command like "click id=ui-id-25"

Tags: selenium-ide

I am recording the site of online ticket booking and while recording the script, scripts records the command like "click id=ui-id-25". Once I finish recording the script and click on play to run current test case. I get error message like 'Element id=ui-id-25 not found'.

So please let me know what's the meaning of the command 'click id=ui-id-25' and why its recorded, even though while running the script we get error message.

Comment: I bet your id is generated dynamically. Try to write locator avoiding id (for example using xpath).

Answer (score 1):

**The meaning of the command**

The command `click id=someId` tells Selenium to simulate the click on the element on the page which has `id = "someId"`. If there is no element with this `id` on the page at the time of execution of this command; we have the error telling that `Element ... not found !`.

**Why it's recorded**

Selenium IDE records actions you do in the page. Clicking an element of the page is an action so it's recorded.

**Why we get this error**

This is actually because Selenium IDE doesn't record "waiting time". If, while recording, you do `action 1` and wait for an element to be shown (even for 0.5 second) and then click on this element. For Selenium, this is only two actions :

1. doing `action 1`
2. clicking the element

and so when running the test case, it try to click the element directly after doing the `action 1` without waiting. In this case, it doesn't find the element and gives the error !

**Okey, what is the solution ?**

One simple solution is to add the command `waitForElementPresent` to wait for the element to be present on the page before clicking it. You can do that while recording the test case right click on the element and selecting this command before clicking on it. Or you can add it to the test case when seeing this error. Add it just before the `click` command causing the error and give it the same argument as the `click` ( ie. `id = ui-id-25` in your case)

Hope this answers your questions